# Swift FMResultSet nil / Getting row count

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I'm working on an app that pulls data from the internet, and has a local database to store that data, during times that no connection is available.

I'm able to store and pull the data in the database just fine, but I can't seem to get the count of the items in the database.

Here's my code:

```
func getCount(tableName:String) -> Int {
    let sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM " + tableName
    print(sql) // <---- prints out the complete SQL, works fine
    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    var count = 0
    if resultSet != nil {
        print("Database not empty")
        while resultSet.next() {
            count += 1
        }
        return count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

**The Problem**

Unfortunately, it would seem as if even my `getCount` function doesn't work, as it always returns 0. It wouldn't even get past the `if resultSet != nil` part.

Yes, there's at least one item in the database table, and manually putting that query in SQLiteBrowser gets me results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is overlooking error handling.

Look at your code: what are the code paths that can have your function return 0?

There are two:

1. There is a resultSet, and the resultSet.next() method returns nil (which means no row)
2. there is no resultSet (which means a database error).

Since `SELECT COUNT(id)` statements can't return no row, this means that you have a database error.

And since you ignore it (by returning 0) you don't know what happens, and here you are, clueless, on stack overflow.

In short: do handle errors.

Comment: I know that FMDB makes everything it can to make as if errors did not exist, so it's not always easy do handle errors with FMDB. As a consequence, you may consider using another library. For example, check http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift.

Actually, looking at your getCount() function, I think that you might be interested in GRDB's Records: http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift#records

Comment: Very well. How do I do error handling with that code? As I've said before, I have no problem storing and fetching data from the database. I'd rather not use another library - I don't have that kind of authentication.